# vscode generate large configuration files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have noticed that the `.vscode` files have 1.4 GB in each folder that I open a code. Why these file have become so large? Is there any way to stop making these large files? I need to `scp` code folder between remote machine and I need to remove these files frequently.

I use `version: 1.32.3` on Limux Mint 18.3. and the following extensions:

Python, C++, Prettier, Peacoke, GitLense.

```
.vscode/
└── ipch
    ├── 21fd2401553c84f8
    │   ├── functions.ipch
    │   └── mmap_address.bin
    ├── 944dcfa22b114a8c
    │   ├── main.ipch
    │   └── mmap_address.bin
    └── 9f0098f535f71055
        ├── kuramoto.ipch
        └── mmap_address.bin

4 directories, 6 files
```

Thank you for any guide.

Comment: I can remove the .vscode file from makefile, I just was curious. Perhaps Cpp extension is the reason, cause it make 470 MB file for each cpp file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in the `ipch` folder are IntelliSense cache files generated by the [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools). The maintainer has described how you can the customize cache path and size limit [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3347#issuecomment-476277174).